# Prove that the Simson line of $P$ bisects the segment $HP$ from the orthocentre $H$ to $P$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with orthocentre $H$ and circumcircle $\odot(ABC)$.
Suppose $P\in\odot(ABC)$. Let $\gamma$ be Simson's line of $P$ wrt $ABC$.

Prove that $\gamma$ bisects $PH$.

Comment: [Simpson's Line](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimsonLine.html)            The preceding link redirects to Wolfram Math World.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P_A,P_B,P_C$ be the projections of $P$ on the sides $BC,AC,AB$; let $Q$ be the intersection between $AH$ and the Simson's line of $P$. We want to show that $HQ=PP_A$. If we call $H_A$ the symmetric of $H$ with respect to the $BC$ side, we have that $H_A$ lies on the circumcircle of $ABC$, so, in order to prove that $HQ=PP_A$, it is sufficient to show that $PP_A QH_A$ is an isosceles trapezoid.
Let $\theta=\widehat{P_C P_A B}=\widehat{P_B P_A C}$. Since $P P_A P_C B$ and $P P_A C P_B$ are cyclic quadrilaterals, we have $\theta=\widehat{P_C P B}=\widehat{P_B P C}$, too.

Now:
$$\widehat{P_A Q H_A}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta,$$
and:
$$\widehat{P H_A Q}=\widehat{P H_A A}=\widehat{P B A}=\widehat{P B P_C}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta.$$
Since $PP_A$ and $QH_A$ are both ortogonal to $BC$, $PP_A Q H_A$ is an isosceles trapezoid and we have $PP_A=QH$, QED.